Overriding AOSP keyboard
Error:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.inputmethod.latin.CarIME" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~6CnZ_EwlgHaoEjQXjHx4lA==/com.android.inputmethod.latin-gLDFp7uEfMCiBHMTjxVdHA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~6CnZ_EwlgHaoEjQXjHx4lA==/com.android.inputmethod.latin-gLDFp7uEfMCiBHMTjxVdHA==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]

Manifest:

Android.bp file
android_app { name: "CustomKeyboard",

certificate: "platform", privileged: true, platform_apis: true,

manifest: "AndroidManifest.xml",

srcs: ["java/**/*.java"],

resource_dirs: ["res"],

overrides: ["LatinIME"],

 libs: [
        "android.car",      
    ],

aaptflags: ["--auto-add-overlay", "--extra-packages",
"com.google.android.material", "--extra-packages",
"androidx.appcompat", "--extra-packages", "androidx.constraintlayout",
"--extra-packages", "androidx.navigation", ],

static_libs: [ "androidx.appcompat_appcompat",
"com.google.android.material_material",
"androidx-constraintlayout_constraintlayout",
"androidx.navigation_navigation-ui",
"androidx.navigation_navigation-fragment", "android.car", ],

 aapt_include_all_resources: true, optimize: { enabled: false,
//proguard_flags_files: ["proguard.flags"], },

dex_preopt: {
        enabled: true, },

product_variables: {
        pdk: {
            enabled: false,
        },
     }, }

I am trying to override packages/apps/Car/LatinIME/CarLatinIME in the vendor folder and create a custom Keyboard application. I am able to build apk however while running the app custom keyboard crashes. However, I am getting above error. What could be wrong?

You should always post code in text and not in image, so that it is easier for others to experiment with

Why image in place of code ?

Seems like there's no class com.android.inputmethod.latin.CarIME, the closest I could find in the AOSP source code is com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME and you can find the class here
Probably correcting this in the manifest file will help you proceed with a successful build
<service android:name="com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME"> // Notice the name here
   // Other code
</service>

